# How can I make a change to a Drupal field?

Tags: drupal-9

Good morning, I am learning how Drupal works and I want to make a call to the rest api to be able to modify a field, my big problem is that imsomnia always throws me the 406 error

json: {

```
{
    "data": {
            "field_nombre": [
        {
            "value": "Tortillas  6 piezas update"
        }
    ]
        
    }

}
}
```

headers: {
Content-Type: "application/json"
}

API:
https://abarrotes.msalazar.dev/node/81?_format=json

RESULT: 406